# procmail save attachment with received date in filename

Tags: email, procmail

Every day we receive an e-mail from e.g. foo@example.tld with an attachment, the filename is e.g. `report.xlsx`

How can I save the file with the received date? e.g. `20180131_report.xlsx` and how can I filter on the subject or the sender?

My **~/.procmailrc**:

```
:0
*^content-Type:
{
    :fw
    | ripmime --overwrite --no-nameless -i - -d /dir/to/save/attachment
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your Procmail or the receiving MTA is configured to put in a [`From_` line](http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#from) before the message proper, this pseudo-header generally already contains the date. You'll need to parse it, which is a drag, so unless this is a system where you really need to optimize for perfomance (hundreds of matches per second on this condition?) the absolutely easiest solution is to call `date +%Y%m%d`.

To match on either of two unrelated headers, just put them both in a regex with `|`:

```
:0
* ^Content-type:
* ^From:(.*\<)?foo@example\.tld|^Subject: Your daily report
| ripmime --overwrite --no-nameless -i - -d /dir/to/save/attachment/$(date +%Y%m%d)_report.xslx
```

*(Bug here; see update below.)*

The `fw` flags don't make sense in this context so I took them out (and actually I'm not sure the `Content-type:` condition makes a lot of sense either; most messages will have it anyway, these days).

If you have more complex conditions you want to combine, you can use a fundamental principle from logic called de Morgan's laws. There is no *direct* syntax in Procmail to say "this condition or that condition", but [you can refactor this](http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#oring) to "not ((not this condition) and (not that condition))."

```
:0
* ! this condition
* ! that condition
{ } # nothing happens here
:0E # else
{ LOG="at least one of them matched
" }
```

Or simply use scoring;

```
:0
* 1^0 this condition
* 1^0 that conditon
{ LOG="at least one of them matched
" }
```

**Update:**

It looks like [`ripmime`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ripmime) doesn't actually support (extracting or) naming an individual attachment. The easiest solution is perhaps a `cron` job which renames the latest arrival a bit before midnight (or if you know when it arrives, a bit after the latest time you expect it):

```
 55 23 * * * cd /dir/to/save/attachment && mv report.xslx "$(date +%%Y%%m%%d)"_report.xslx
```

Notice how (peculiarly) you need to double any percent signs in a `cron` command! You would obviously revert the Procmail recipe above to simply have `ripmime` save to `/dir/to/save/attachment`

Alternatively, I would rename the attachment right after it arrives, perhaps while also tightening the conditions considerably. The following includes a fair amount of guesswork as to how *exactly* the message which delivers the attachment is encoded -- it could choose between a number of different content types, MIME structures, MIME header conventions, etc, so it probably doesn't work without some tweaking.

```
:0
* ^From:(.*\<)?foo@example\.tld
* ^Subject: Your daily report
* HB ?? ^Content-type: application/(octet-stream|vnd\.openxmlformats-officedocument\.spreadsheetml\.sheet|vnd\.ms-here-be-dragons-xslx); filename="?report.xslx
| ( cd dir/to/save/attachment; \
    ripmime --overwrite --no-nameless -i - -d . && \
    mv report.xslx $(date +%Y%m%d)"_report.xslx )
```

The `Content-type:` header might not contain the filename; it could (and these days should) be specified in `Content-Disposition:` but many senders put it in both places for backwards compatibility. The filename should properly be RFC2231-encoded which means a number of optional fields could be populated where I have conveniently assumed they will be empty, like they were when ASCII filenames were the only game in town.

Notice also how I require the sender *and* the subject to match now. The `HB ??` says (imprecisely) to look for a match either in the main message headers, or somewhere in the body. Properly speaking, the match should be in the headers of a MIME body part in the latter case, but Procmail has no easy way to specify this.

Comment: The babel of Excel content types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937465/what-is-correct-content-type-for-excel-files

Comment: One other option for renaming could be to write the file to a randomly-named directory and then rename whatever file is in that directory to `report.xlsx`. It may also be possible to use the `--postfix` option to `ripmime`, but that doesn't cater for the attachment having a name different from `report.xlsx`.

Comment: Mm yeah, `ripmime` without `--overwrite` will take adequate precautions to not replace an existing file; but then you need additional logic to figure out what it did. I assume the OP used `--overwrite` consciously to replace any previous file.

Answer (score 3):

Answering each of your questions:

1. You can call out to external commands from within a recipe, so you can do something like this to define variable `TODAY`:

   ```
   TODAY=`date +%Y%m%d`
   ```

   You can then refer to it in your recipes:

   ```
   ripmime --overwrite --no-nameless -i - -d /dir/to/save/attachment/$TODAY_report_xlsx
   ```

   If you need to determine the filename dynamically, adjust the recipe accordingly.
2. To filter on a subject *and* a sender, you can do something like:

   ```
   :0
   * ^content-Type:
   * ^From:.* foo@example.tld
   * ^Subject:.*Report
   {
   ....
   ```